# How to access Jenkins using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jenkins

I'm trying to make a script (using Javascript & JQuery) that will retrieve some information from Jenkins. In particular, I'm trying to get it to access the api of a build (build's URL + "api/json") and then getting some information with that.
I'm having trouble getting the content of the URL and I think it's an issue with authentication because I can access other public websites with json content.

This is what I have right now:

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
        },
        url: myurlapi,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,

        success: function (data) {
            // what i'm going to do
        }


    })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been pretty stuck on this for a while now.

Thanks

EDIT: 
I get the following error when I try to do this:
"error: NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load '*url i'm trying to access*'."

Comment: What is the response/error you're getting?

Comment: @Sasang I get the following error: "error: NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load "URL I'M TRYING TO ACCESS".

Comment: This could be a cross domain issue, do you have CORS enabled on your server?

Comment: Try curl `myurlapi` and post output. And what happens when you paste the URL in your browser?

Comment: And is the Jenkins machine reachable from the machine doing the Ajax request?

Comment: @Sasang I think that could be the problem. I'm not an admin on the Jenkins server so I'm trying to enable CORS.

Comment: @Rik What do you mean by curl? sorry I'm not familiar with it. When I paste the URL in the browser I get to it fine, I have access to the Jenkins server from the computer I'm on

Comment: Try typing in the URL in a browser on the machine that you run the Ajax call. That should show the output

Comment: With curl you can do http calls from the command line

Comment: @Rik thanks, when I type in the URL or when I try running curl "myurlapi" I see my desired output, which is just a bunch of data written in json

Comment: Try logging the error in your code, probably some `onerror` and see the http_code that is returned. That might give you a good impression. Also see if you can print the entire path, to check if it is actually what you are trying to call

Comment: @Rik It was an issue with CORS. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
'$.ajax({ url: 'http://<hosturl>/jenkins/job/BuildProvision/buildWithParameters?token=<jenkins-token>,&delay=0&HOSTNAME=\"'+hostname+'\"&HOSTIP=\"'+hostip+'\"&USER=\"'+user+'\"&PASS=\"'+pass+'\"&RELEASE=\"'+release+'\"&BUILD=\"'+build+'\"', 
          method: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          crossDomain: true,
          contentType:'application/json',  
          beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.withCredentials = true;
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic <your user token>');
          },
          success: function(data){'
```